# MS-Access select the greatest value less than current value matching criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet

My situation is that I have a table that when simplified, looks like this:

```
Sort| IsHeader
1   | 0
2   | 0
3   | 1
4   | 0
5   | 0
6   | 1
7   | 0
8   | 0
9   | 0
```

I am trying to make a query that will Update a new HeaderSort line for each detail line to show which header that line belongs to, with this end result:

```
Sort| IsHeader| HeaderSort
1   |  0      | 0
2   |  0      | 0
3   |  1      | 3
4   |  0      | 3
5   |  0      | 3
6   |  1      | 6
7   |  0      | 6
8   |  0      | 6
9   |  0      | 6
```

In T-SQL I can do it quite easily:

```
update MT set HeaderSort = 
(
    select isnull(max(Sort),0) from MyTable where Sort <= MT.Sort and IsHeader = 1
)  as HeaderSort 
from MyTable MT
```

My attempt at an access version is as follows:

```
Update MyTable set HeaderSort =
(
    select nz(max(Sort),0) from MyTable where Sort <= MT.Sort and IsHeader = 1
)
```

This, however gives a "Operation must use an updatable query." error.
Is my error in the logic for getting the values, or just some ms-access syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Operation must use an updatable query.* is a general error encountered when not all tables referred to in an update statement are updateable. Unfortunately, subqueries rarely are.

You can work around the error by using a `DLookup` instead of a subquery:

```
Update MyTable set HeaderSort = DLookUp("nz(max(Sort),0)", "MyTable", "Sort <= " & MyTable.Sort & " and IsHeader = 1")
```

Comment: That's not true. `DLookUp` is not a true domain aggregate, but rather a recordset wrapper that returns the first result, as far as I understand. You can use aggregates and expressions in `DLookUp`. `DLookUp("Max(Field1)", "MyTable")` is just a less optimized equal to `DMax("Field1", "MyTable")`

Comment: I guess I was thinking along the line of having it completely in a sql statement, but for my purposes, the DLookup method works just fine.